# Sum all ascii values for every character of varchar in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I have a table I want to partition based on HASH. This table has a column with varchar, which is the key I want to use to partition.

Ofc. I can't partition based on HASH with varchar, therefore I will SUM all the ASCII values of each character in the varchar.

I hope to get some help to stitch together a function, which takes a varchar parameter and returns the SUM as an INTEGER.

I have tried several variations - some of them commented out -, this is how it looks so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_string_ascii_values(theString varchar)
    RETURNS INTEGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
    $$
    DECLARE
        theSum INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        -- Sum on all ascii values coming from the every single char from the input varchar.
        SELECT SUM( val )
            FROM LATERAL ( SELECT ASCII( UNNEST( STRING_TO_ARRAY( LOWER(theString), null) ) ) ) AS val
        INTO theSum;

        --SELECT SUM(val) FROM ASCII( UNNEST( STRING_TO_ARRAY( LOWER(theString), null) ) ) AS val INTO theSUM;
        --RETURN SUM( ASCII( UNNEST( STRING_TO_ARRAY( LOWER(theString), null) ) ) );

        RETURN theSUM;
    END;
    $$;
```

I hope someone will be able to write and explain a solution to this problem.

Comment: This might not be a good idea, if you have a value 'BB' the sum of ASCII codes is `66+66=132` which is the same for 'AC' `65+67=132` what is the advantage of generating a hash over using an identity column?

Comment: @Simeon That's true, but that doesn't hurt in my case. The varchar in question is actually an ID on a device, but it comes from different vendors. Therefore all IDs which get the same INTEGER value will go into the same table, and that's quite alright :)

Comment: Of course you can use a `varchar` as partitioning key. What makes you think you cannot do that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe My current knowledge of HASH partitioning in PostgreSQL, but please enlighten me :)

Comment: Well, now you know better. Try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using SELECT to sum the characters, you can loop through the string instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_string_ascii_values(input text) RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  hash int = 0;
  pos int = 0;
BEGIN
  WHILE pos <= length(input) LOOP
    hash =  hash + ascii(upper(substr(input, pos, 1)));
    pos = pos + 1;
  END LOOP;
 RETURN hash;
END;
$$;
```

Here is a link to a dbfiddle to demonstrate https://dbfiddle.uk/yfhpHyT1

Comment: Thanks @Simeon!
It almost works as intended, but it skips the first character currently.
https://dbfiddle.uk/CPCFWelT

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the code to fix that, but according to Laurenz you can partition on varchars so maybe this isn't necessary anymore? Although I do wonder what would be more performant

Comment: Nice, I've put this as the accepted answer. Yes, it seems like you can HASH partition on varchar, and for some reason, I discarded it while I was researching it.